# CSS rounded blurred border

Tags: css, ionic4

I have an ionic4 app where i need to achieve an img effect similar to the one in the card below. Blur at the edges down to the centre and then clear at the center with another white border

[image]

How can i achieve this? Please ignore the edit icon

Comment: What have you tried so far? I would probably go with an SVG solution, although CSS has decent support for `clip-path` and `filter: blur()`. Hope that can point you in the right direction :o)

Comment: Hello friend. I'm not really good with my css. Im kinda lost with all youve said. :). can you throw more light?

Comment: Hi. I finally got it working. With your hint!. This is much much appreciated

Comment: Glad you found a solution that works! If you think you can help someone else facing the same issue, you can even post an answer to your own question :o)

Comment: Ive just done that. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Uurgh. It works well on the  browser but makes the apk really slow as its rendering all images twice.  Anyway you can help?. I think i got it the wrong way

Answer (score 1):

```
<!-- Floating image-->
<img class="cardImage" src="{{card.img}}"><br>

<!-- Background -->
<img class="cardImage2" src="{{card.img}}"><br>


.cardImage {
  width: 92%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border:1px solid #021a40;
  position: absolute;
  clip-path: circle();
  top: 25px;
  margin-left: 4%;
  height: 110px;
}

.cardImage2 {
  width: 92%;
  object-fit: cover;
  opacity: 0.25;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-left: 4%;
  height: 130px;
}
```